# Bottom-Up Approach - Echo the nav of parent and child in which a certain article is placed ("Parent > Children > Children2nd") - with MySql and PHP

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

I'm looking forward to implement a typical "nav" section for the articles in my website. Something like this:

**Folder > SubFolder > SubSubFolder**

To this end, I think that the best way is to create a database of two tables.

The **first** one is called "*Category*":

| id | title | parentid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Folder1 | NULL |
| 2 | Folder2 | NULL |
| 3 | Folder3 | NULL |
| 4 | SubFolder1 | 1 |
| 5 | SubFolder2 | 1 |
| 6 | SubFolder3 | 2 |
| 7 | SubFolder4 | 3 |
| 8 | SubSubFolder1 | 6 |
| 9 | SubSubFolder2 | 6 |

The **second** one is called "*Articles*":

| id | text | lastparentid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lorem Ipsum ... | 7 |
| 2 | Lorem Ipsum ... | 3 |
| 3 | Lorem Ipsum ... | 5 |
| 4 | Lorem Ipsum ... | 2 |
| 5 | Lorem Ipsum ... | 3 |
| 6 | Lorem Ipsum ... | 5 |
| 7 | Lorem Ipsum ... | 8 |

The relationship between the two tables is based on the "lastparentid" value in Articles table which will point to the Folder in Category table.
For instance, the article n. 1 is in the Folder which id is n. 7 --> so it is in the SubFolder4 (which is a child of Folder3).
Therefore, when a user lands on an article, I will have only the id of the "folder" that the article is placed in and I will have to recreate the entire tree up to the parent.

**EDIT 1:**

To this end and in order to echo the nav, the user Bob (which I thanks a lot) suggest the following code:

```
with recursive cteCategories
  AS (select 1 as level,
             id,
             title,
             parentid
        from Category
        where id = 0
      union all
      select cte.level+1 as level,
             c.id,
             c.title,
             c.parentid
        from Category c
        inner join cteCategories cte
          on c.parentid = cte.id)
select level,
       id,
       title,
       LPAD(title, LENGTH(title)+((level-1)*3), ' ') as indented_title,
       parentid
  from cteCategories
```

However, this follows an approach top-down (from the parent to ALL the children). On the contrary, I need to create the tree from the bottom (represented by the folder pointed by "lastparentid" value of the article) to the wider parent.

For istance: for article n. 7, the nav will be "**Folder2 > Subfolder3 > SubSubFolder1**"

Please note that I don't have to print all the subfolder that are in each folder, but only go up to the top of thr tree.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which version of MySQL you're using so I'll assume you're using version 8 which supports recursive queries. I don't understand how your `Category` table relates to your `Articles` table so I'll have to ignore that, but here's a recursive query to pull all the data from `Category` in hierarchical fashion:

```
with recursive cteCategories
  AS (select 1 as level,
             id,
             title,
             parentid
        from Category
        where id = 0
      union all
      select cte.level+1 as level,
             c.id,
             c.title,
             c.parentid
        from Category c
        inner join cteCategories cte
          on c.parentid = cte.id)
select level,
       id,
       title,
       LPAD(title, LENGTH(title)+((level-1)*3), ' ') as indented_title,
       parentid
  from cteCategories
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d84ff1ca178b25343a1535535dcc795e)

In the dbfiddle I added a row with `id=0` to serve as a top-level parent to all of the subtrees.

### EDIT

OP indicates that he wants to go from bottom-to-top in the tree structure. No sooner said than done:

```
with recursive cteBottomToTop
  AS (select id, parentid
        from Category
        where id = 7  -- start here
      union all
      select c.id, c.parentid
        from Category c
        inner join cteBottomToTop cte
          on c.id = cte.parentid)
select *
  from cteBottomToTop
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f8eb4ec074c91394f7e9e47bc357bef)

Comment: Thanks, the lastparentid value in Articles table will point to the Folder in Category table. For instance, the article n. 1 is in the Folder which id is n. 7 --> so is in the SubFolder4 (which is a child of Folder3). 
Therefore, when a user lands on an article, I will have only the id of the "folder" that the article is placed in and I will have to recreate the entire tree up to the parent.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but your solution seems to work only with an approach top-bottom (from the parent to the last child). On the contrary, I would like an approach bottom-up: form the subsubfolder of the article up to the wider parent.

Comment: I added an example of going from bottom to top as well.